# Show only accurate hours in DATEDIFF SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, db2

I am trying to convert

```
Select 
    Dept_ID, Student_CODE,
    ((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIME_OUT -TIME_IN)))* 1.0e0) / 60) HOURS
from 
    d.TIME_CLOCK
where 
    SYSTEM_DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-09' AND '2015-12-09' and Dept_ID = 109
Group By 
    Dept_ID, Student_CODE
```

above db2 code to SQL Server code as below

```
Select 
    Dept_ID, Student_CODE,
    ((SUM(-DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TIME_OUT, TIME_IN)) * 1.0e0) / 60) HOURS 
from 
    TIME_CLOCK 
where 
    SYSTEM_DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-09' AND '2015-12-09' 
    AND (Dept_ID =  109)               
Group By 
    Dept_ID, Student_CODE
```

But while doing this I am getting different values for the `HOURS` column for both the queries in spite of `TIME_OUT` (`datetime`) and `TIME_IN` (`datetime`) values being same.

How can I get accurate `Hours` in decimals in SQL Server?

Comment: What value/s are you getting and what value/s are you expecting?

Comment: 1) Your values aren't in "decimals" in either case, but (binary) floating point, there's a difference.  Which do you actually want?  Floats are good for "close enough" math like for physics, but decimals are used for things like money, which I suspect you want here.  2) [Don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  3) `TIMESTAMPDIFF` on DB2 returns an **ESTIMATE** (because of the result of the date subtraction), so I'd assume SQL Server is returning you correct results.